# Laravel - Allowed Memory Exhausted on Observer Trigger for Updated Model to be Returned

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using IntertiaJS have a Vue component that displays a model's information, and also allows the user to update the model and PATCH on the backend:

In the < script setup > tag of the front end component:

```
const postMyModelEdit = () => {
    editMode.value = false; // this is just for controlling state on my component
    router.patch('/mymodels/' + props.mymodel.id, {
        name: props.mymodel.name,
        description: props.mymodel.description,
        ...
        expected_start_date: props.mymodel.expected_start_date,
        expected_end_date: props.mymodel.expected_end_date,
        ..
    });
}
```

When this is send to the backend, I update the model and return to this page, but my model also has an Observer on it that checks when *expected_start_date* or *expected_end_date* changes and updates a field called *duration_in_months* on the model.

MyModelController.php

```
public function update(Request $request, MyModel $mymodel)
{
    $mymodel->update($request->validate([
        'name' => ['max:255'],
        'description' => ['nullable', 'max:255'],
         ...
        'expected_start_date' => ['date'],
        'expected_end_date' => ['nullable', 'date'],
        ...
    ]));

    return redirect()->route('mymodels.show', $mymodel);
}
```

MyModelObserver.php

```
public function updated(MyModel $mymodel): void
{
    if ($mymodel->isDirty('expected_start_date') || $mymodel->isDirty('expected_end_date')) {
        $mymodel->updateDurationInMonths();
    }
}
```

Finally, in MyModel.php:

```
public function updateDurationInMonths()
{
    $startDate = Carbon::parse($this->expected_start_date);
    $endDate = Carbon::parse($this->expected_end_date);
    $this->duration_in_months = $startDate->diffInMonths($endDate);
    $this->save();
}
```

When I try to update the model, all fields work fine except when I update either *expected_start_date* or *expected_end_date*. When trying to do so, I get a 500 error, with the blank screen below, and no entry in the logs. I do however get an error in my Terminal telling me that I've exceeded memory.

[image: blank screen error]
[image: memory allocation exceeded error]

These operations are pretty basic and should not be exceeding the memory. Maybe this has something to do with observing on a model that I'm updating and returning, but would appreciate some help to figure this one out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you see an "Allowed Memory Exhausted" error when an infinite loop happens. I don't see something that leads to an endless loop in your code. It could be somewhere else in your code that you don't add to your question.

However, making an update operation in the listener of an update event is always dangerous. Any missed points can lead to an infinite loop.

I suggest modifying the `duration_in_months` field in the updating event. This way, you will avoid possible infinite loops and improve the database performance by reducing update operations.

MyModel.php:

```php
protected static function boot() {
    static::updating(function($mymodel) {
        if ($mymodel->isDirty('expected_start_date') || $mymodel->isDirty('expected_end_date')) {
            $startDate = Carbon::parse($mymodel->expected_start_date);
            $endDate = Carbon::parse($mymodel->expected_end_date);
            $mymodel->duration_in_months = $startDate->diffInMonths($endDate);

            // You must not call "$mymodel->save()" because it will automatically saved.

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're right in that that is where the endless loop is, thanks. I ended up taking a slightly different approach, but this will work I believe.